# Given the relation find if it is transitive

Tags: relations

Given $S = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$

Relation $R=\{(x,y)|x-y=0\}\subset S\mathbb x S$

Create the set $M = S\mathbb x S$

$M = \{\\
(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), \\
(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), \\
(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), \\
(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), \\
(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5)\\\}$

Applying the relation $R=\{(x,y)|x-y=0\}\subset M$

Gives the $OUTPUT = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5)\}$

I understand this relation is `reflexive`. And I need help in understanding, how this relation is also `transitive`?

For a relation to te `transitive` $x=y$ and $y=a$ then $x=a$. How can I apply the `transitive` rule in this case?

Comment: Your relation $R$ (on the set $S$) is equality, so yes, it is transitive, there is nothing more to write than the definition in your last line.

Answer (score 2):

In order to show *[transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation)* of the relation $R$ we have to show that for all $x,y,z\in S$
\begin{align*}
(x,y)\in R\quad\mathrm{and}\quad (y,z)\in R \quad\mathrm{implies }\quad (x,z)\in R\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> Let $x,y,z\in S$. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{matrix}
> (x,y)\in R\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=y\\
> (y,z)\in R\quad\Rightarrow\quad y=z\\
> \end{matrix}\ \Bigr\} \quad\Rightarrow\quad  x=z \quad\Rightarrow\quad (x,z)\in R
> \end{align*}
> and (1) follows.